# How can I bind an event on a selectedIndex changed on <select> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By using jQuery how do I attach an event on the following select element so that on index change it alerts "I have changed!"?

```
<select id="selCars">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){  
   $("#selCars").change(function() {
       alert("I have changed!");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onchange` event. When the `selectionIndex` of the `<select>` element changes, the `change` event is fired.

Execute this piece of code after the element is created. If you want to add the on load, wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` , abbreviated by `$(function(){...})`

```
$("#selCars").change(function(){
    // Do something...
    //this refers to the `<select>` element
    var newoption = $(this)
    var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);

    //Example: 
    alert("I have changed!");
})
```

Comment: Added a sharp, to prefix the ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selCars").change(function() {
    alert("I have changed!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selCars').change(function(){
    alert( "I have changed!" );
})
```